# Create hyperlinks based on matching names in a directory

Tags: excel

I have a Column of data in excel with employee names, I am trying to hyper link each cell to the Employee file in a directory, the names for the folders and cells are formatted identically.  I could manually go through and hyperlink these however that would be very tedious and I am hoping there is a function that can accomplish this that I am not familiar with.

I think this is also doable using macros/vba however that is something I have not used in the past.

Thanks for your time and feedback!

Comment: Dear @Axios_Andrew: did I solve your problem? If yes, please "accept" my answer by clicking the check symbol next to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the =HYPERLINK function in column B. Assuming that the files are in C:\directory\ and that they are called "content in column A".xlsx -- try this:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\directory\"&A1&".xlsx", A1)
```

Source: [Microsoft: HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/HYPERLINK-function-d1a84847-ceaf-4e8b-b583-55787a69b125)